# How do you abstract some expression to BNF?

Tags: bnf

For example :

```
waldo:=fern+alpha/-beta^gamma;
```

The above **arithmetical expression** may be abstracted by this BNF(there may be some difference from standard BNF,but lets ignore it for now):

```
AEXP = AS $AS ;

AS = .ID ':=' EX1 ';' ;

EX1 = EX2 $( '+' EX2 / '-' EX2 ) ;

EX2 = EX3 $( '*' EX3 / '/' EX3 ) ;

EX3 = EX4 $( '^' EX3 ) ;

EX4 = '+' EX5 / '-' EX5 / EX5 ;

EX5 = .ID / .NUMBER / '(' EX1 ')' ;

.END
```

But the `EX1~EX5` abstraction is not so intuitive to me.(I don't quite understand how they are crafted in the first place)

Is there any steps to follow when normalizing such expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate this notation to EBNF directly.

Naming categories EX1 through EX5 is not an uncommon way of specifying operator precedence.  In fact it is a good one, IMHO, especially in some languages that have 15 or more precedence levels, like C and C++ do. :)

You can rename them to expression, term, factor, primary, etc. (or whatever terms make sense to you).

ADDENDUM

If you need a translation of the above into more traditional EBNF, here is how I would do it:

```
AEXP => AS+
AS   => id ':=' EX1 ';'
EX1  => EX2 (('+' | '-') EX2)*
EX2  => EX3 (('*' | '/') EX3)*
EX3  => EX4 ('^' EX3)*
EX4  => ('+'|'-')? EX5
EX5  => id | number | '(' EX1 ')'
```

I use '*' for zero or more, '+' for one or more, and '?' for optional. It is pretty cool how operator precedence is handled here, I think.

ADDENDUM 2:

Please note: It appears that the rule for EX3 is wrong.  The way it stands now you can get parse trees like this

```
                  EX3
                   |
     +---+----+----+----+---------+
     |   |    |    |    |    |    |
    EX4  ^   EX3   ^   EX3   ^   EX3
            / | \               / | \
         EX4  ^  EX3         EX4  ^  EX3
```

So writing `a^b^c^d^e^f` could mean `a^(b^c)^d^(e^f)`.  But in fact there are other ways to make this tree.  The grammar is ambiguous.

It appears the designer of the grammar wanted to make the `^` operator right-associative.  But to do so, the rule should have been

```
EX3 => EX4 ('^' EX3)?
```

Now the grammar is no longer ambiguous.  Look how the derivation of `a^b^c^d^e^f` MUST now proceed:

```
          EX3
         / | \
      EX4  ^  EX3
             / | \
          EX4  ^  EX3
                 / | \
              EX4  ^  EX3
                     / | \
                  EX4  ^  EX3
                         / | \
                      EX4  ^  EX3
```

Now `a^b^c^d^e^f` can ONLY parse as `a^(b^(c^(d^(e^f))))`

An alternative is to rewrite the rule as `EX3 => EX4 ('^' EX4)*` and have a side rule saying "OBTW the caret is right associative."

Comment: Can you be more specific how to translate `waldo:=fern+alpha/-beta^gamma;` to EBNF? I'm at a loss when arriving at `EX1`..

Comment: @JeRog, added response in my answer.

Comment: Why is it `EX3 => EX4 (('^' EX3)*`, neither `EX3 => EX4 (('^' EX4)*` nor `EX3 => EX4 (('^' EX1)*`? I just wonder how can we derive the EBNF by observation..

Comment: The reason for the odd-looking EX3 rule is that the original designer of the grammar probably wanted to force the notion of right-associativity of `^` into the language.  However, if he or she wanted to do so, then the rule _should have_ been written like this: `EX3 => EX4 ('^' EX3)` -- that is, without the Kleene star.  As to how we can write EBNF "by observation" the answer is you can do these things easily with experience.  Once you start looking at a lot of grammars and you take a shot at designing your own, you will recognize common patterns and get pretty good at it.

Comment: How do you know `^` is right-associativity from `EX4 ('^' EX3)*`? I think that depends on the implementation and we can't infer it just from syntax..

Comment: Two things: (1) drawing syntax trees for the EX3 with and without the stars will show you that only without stars will you get true right associativity.  (2) Don't design a grammar where you go "up" to previous EX rules without parentheses, otherwise you can introduce ambiguity.  So I would strongly advise against your EX2 solution.

Comment: Can you illustrate that syntax tree for EX3? It seems I can't get the conclusion of yours by the tree.

Comment: Sorry, Je, there was a typo.  I left off a `?`.  I've added to the answer again because this comment thread is getting too long.

Comment: How do you write the side rule saying "OBTW the caret is right associative." ??

Comment: By "side rule" it is meant something outside the formal grammar.  It is literally just a piece of informal natural language text that picks up things that one chose not to put into the formal grammar for whatever reason....